# A decidable language that can't be decided by a circuit ensemble of linear size

Tags: time-complexity, computability, computation-models, decidability

Let Size(O(n)) be the set of languages the can be decided by a circuit ensemble (a sequence of circuits C_i for every natural i s.t input size is i) such that every circuit's size is linear (in input size).
I would like to prove there exists a decidable language that doesn't belong to the set defined above.
I tried using a fixed input size and using an upper bound for the number of possible languages that can be implemented by such circuit, and to show it is a polynomial upper bound (while there are 2^2^n languages). Problem is, I'm pretty sure this proof doesn't hold, because this circuit ensemble consists of C_n which can be in size n2^n and all other circuits are constant on 0, and since n is fixed it can be perceived as an O(1) upper bound for all circuits.

If anyone could help I'd very much appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: It might be killing a fly with a hammer, but I think this follows from time hierarchy theorem and the fact that a linear size circuit can be evaluated in time $O(n^2)$. That is, by time hierarchy, there exist languages which require time $\Omega(n^3)$, so take one of those languages. Certainly it cannot have a linear size circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You can show more: there is a function in $\mathsf{EESPACE}$ (doubly exponential space) which has *maximal* circuit complexity. Given an input $x$ of length $n$, enumerate all Boolean circuits with $n$ inputs in increasing order of size, until you encounter all Boolean functions. Choose a Boolean function $f$ of maximal circuit complexity, and output $f(x)$.